# Partial empty $_POST after submit input date

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML form that post datas to a PHP file:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" />
    <input type="date" name="start_date" />
    <button type="button">Save</button>
</form>
```

I submit my form filling up both `first_name` and `start_date`, then I print `$_POST` and I get only `first_name` in my array.

Is there any weird thing I am missing?

---

**SOLVED:**

Stupid not closed `div`, apologize to you all guys for wasting time, about 1000 HTML rows i didn't see!

Comment: We need to see the php.

Comment: it's just `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: See the answer then.

Comment: Try print_r($_POST['first_name']); and print_r($_POST['start_date']);

Comment: already tried, `print_r($_POST['start_date']);` is empty

Comment: try if its empty when you change date type into text. Just to see if it works. You need to be able to fetch each one like i recommended.

Comment: This is guesswork and more time stands to get wasted. Not just ours, but yours as well. I asked to see the PHP but didn't see an update. You relied on an answer but seems to not have worked. Enable error reporting.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner no PHP, just a print after the form that reload the page, and of cours i wasted time before ask and i'll waste time after ask

Comment: I don't know why, but maybe your server has max_input_vars param set to one? What happened when you change the order of inputs?

Comment: @DaszuOne actually i have 10 input text i simplified the question. anyway if i move the input date before all it print correctly the date. then i `echo ini_get("max_input_vars");` and is set to 1000. that's weird!

Comment: Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<button type="button">Save</button>
```

to this

```
<button type="submit">Save</button>
```

and use this code in your PHP to verify

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it works, save it as test.php...

I don't know what else you have going on as we don't see full code.

```
    <form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" />
    <input type="date" name="start_date" />
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
<?php

 print_r($_POST['first_name']);
echo '</br>';
 print_r($_POST['start_date']); 

  ?>
```

Comment: yeah i also tested it in a new file and it works, i'm using YII2 but nothing weird, i have some more HTML but pretty the same code you wrote up. i'm confused too it should work